# Error Mapping Entity to DTO in AutoMapper

Tags: .net-core, automapper

I have gone through Google and some of the post here on SO but I am not able to understand why my Automapper setup maps some classes where as not others. I am using .net core 3.1 and AutoMapper 10.0.0

Below is my implementation

FactoryOLTPSystemsEntity : entity class
FactoryOLTPSystems :Domain Class(DTO)

These classes are **essentially the same with same properties and there is no change except that they belong to different Namespace**.

Service Registration 
`services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());`

My Mapping class

```
            //This works perfectly fine 
            CreateMap<Routes, RoutesEntity>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.integration_id,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Convert.ToString(src.route_id)))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.line_no,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(src => int.Parse(src.dos_line_no.ToString())))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.sub_part_import_src,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(src => double.Parse(src.subimport_path)))
                 .ForMember(dest => dest.dgs_server_id,
                opt => opt.Ignore());

            //This doesnt
            CreateMap<FactoryOLTPSystemsEntity, FactoryOLTPSystems>().ReverseMap();
```

This is the error I get

```
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
Object -> FactoryOLTPSystems
System.Object -> NameSpace.FactoryOLTPSystems
```

I not sure if I am missing something. Any help would be appreciated ..Cheers!!

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu, I am doing the same thing, but its working for some classes and not of others.

Comment: Start from scratch and make an example _exactly_ as in the docs. I'm sure it will work.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why, but this worked, instead of

```
services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
```

I used the below code for registering AutoMapper in ConfigureService method

```
 var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
                    {
                        mc.AddProfile(new MappingConfig());
                    });
```